404 on a parametered route in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with K8s Ingress
I'm sorry if I might be using a different term, but I don't really know what terms should I use, that's why I'm having a hard time to search this over search engines.
Anyway, I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API and I used a Route attribute on the HTTP GET method of my FileController. The URL format is something like this when debugging on local:
http://localhost:8080/api/file/{appId}/{key}

It is working properly.
But through the Kubernetes ingress, I'm getting a 404 error if I try to access it with this url:
https://example.com/serviceapi/myservice/api/file/{appId}/{key}

All the other Web API endpoints are working properly - just not this one.
Here's the YAML of the ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservice.ingress
  namespace: myservice
  annotations:
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "minion"
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=myservice-webapi rewrite=/"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /serviceapi/myservice/
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
             name: myservice-webapi
             port:
               number: 80


Are you sure that rewrite annotation is correct? Doesn't look like these docs

@Phil I'm using 'nginx.org' instead of 'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io', will there be any issues about using the same values? I tried the master-minion with the latter but it don't work. also, should I also use '/serviceapi/myservice(/|$)(.*)' in the path too? I'm a bit confused on this part but I assume it is some kind of character replacement. will '/serviceapi/myservice/api/file' will be mapped to the path '/api/file' in myservice-webapi? thanks!

Hi eSPiYa, try to use ImplementationSpecific, here is the update setting, please give it a try.

@JasonPan thanks for the effort, but it did not worked. all of the previously working API endpoints became inaccessible/404.

@eSPiYa The gist was updated, try again.

@JasonPan it works now. thanks!

Hi @eSPiYa Can I summarize it as answer below? It may help others ,thanks

When we use nginx.org, we can use ImplementationSpecific for url rewrite.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservice-ingress
  namespace: myservice
  annotations:
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "minion"
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=myservice-webapi rewrite=/$2 break"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /serviceapi/myservice(/|/.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice-webapi
            port:
              number: 80

